# Questions regarding a suspected dangling modifier

Tags: sentence-construction, dangling-modifier

I recently came across a sentence that goes “As a father, it's my job to respect my son's opinion.” In this sentence, the prepositional phrase “as a father” is describing me (the noun “I”). However, this prepositional phrase is not placed right before the noun “my”. Is this sentence ungrammatical? Is there a dangling modifier?

I have another two sets of examples below. Am I right that e.g. 1 is correct whereas e.g. 2 is ungrammatical (ungrammatical in the sense that there is a dangling modifier)?

> E.g. 1 As a politician, Johnny should not respond to citizens on the other side of the political spectrum in this way.
>   E.g. 2 As a politician, the way Johnny responded to citizens on the other side of the political spectrum  was unacceptable.

How about this set of sentences? am I right that e.g. 3 is ungrammatical whereas e.g. 4 is grammatical?

> e.g. 3 As a die-hard fan of Barack Obama, it is my honour to have a personal chat with him.
>   e.g. 4 As a die-hard fan of Barack Obama, I am honoured to have a personal chat with him.

Comment: Your second example is ungrammatical, but not because of the "As a politican" bit.  You could say "As a politician, the way Johnny responded to the citizens was unnacceptable" for a closer comparison to your "father" example.

Comment: Corrected as suggested. Is e.g. 2 still ungrammatical now?

Comment: As a native (Br.Eng) speaker, it does not sound wrong to my ear.  The "father" example also sounds entirely natural.  Neither would stand out to me as problematic if I heard them, or saw them in a book or newspaper.  However, I will stop short of declaring it grammatically correct because I am not an expert on the rules of grammar from a prescriptive perspective.

Comment: I agree that the first example is perfect. We can also find: "My job as a father is to respect my son's opinion." I don't find your E.g. 2 to be good English unless the politician is the speaker: Being a politician, (I think) the way Johnny responded... In my opinion, "the way" interrupts the connection between "as a politician" and "Johnny".

Answer (score 1):

On page 38 of Fowler's *Modern English Usage* (2nd edition revised by Sir Ernest Gowers), we can read:

> 7. As = in the capacity of. When
>      this is used, care must be taken to
>      avoid the mistake corresponding to
>      what is called the UNATTACHED PARTICIPLE;
>      we can say *He gave this advice
>      as leader of the opposition*, or *This advice
>      was given by him as leader*, *he* and
>      *him* supplying the point of attachment;
>      but we cannot say *The advice which he
>      tendered to the Peers was given as leader
>      of the opposition*. The writer of the
>      following has fallen into this trap
>      through being in too great a hurry
>      with his *that*: I *should like to say that
>      as a social worker in this field, without
>      exception, no contraceptive technique
>      had been applied by any of the young
>      women who came to me for assistance*.

According to Fowler, for the appositive to be correct the referent has to be the subject or the agent of the **same** clause. I'd add that the referent can also be the object, as in: *This advice was given to me as a junior.*

In:

> As a politician, the way Johnny responded to citizens on the other side of the political spectrum was unacceptable.

"Johnny" is the subject of a relative clause (*the way (in which) Johnny responded...*) and "as a politician" is thus unattached or dangling because it belongs to the main clause.

I have found no references to possessives functioning as antecedents, but I think anteposed "as"-phrases are acceptable with nouns like *job, position, role, goal*, etc. because they complementize such nouns, the only peculiarity being that, unlike normal complements, those phrases appear before the nouns they refer to:

- My job as a father ...
- As a father, my job ...

That is why I find this sentence:

> As a father, it's my job to respect my son's opinion.

(= It's my job as a father to respect my son's opinion.)

more acceptable than this one ("as a die-heart fan..." does not complementize "honour"):

> As a die-heart fan of Barack Obama, it is my honour to have a personal chat with him.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Gustavson's answer, "as a(n) X" is *not* an appositive phrase. An appositive is a noun or noun phrase that provides an alternative description of the subject and stands side by side with it:

> John, **a politician**, was fond of speaking to the public. *(John is a politician, and he's fond of speaking to the public)*

"As a(n) X" is a prepositional phrase and doesn't just alternatively describe the subject, but also implies causality between being X and the rest of the sentence:

> John, **as a politician**, was fond of speaking to the public. *(John is fond of speaking to the public **because** he's a politician)*

So, your googling got you a bit of a red herring.